# Postgres обнулить байт при set_bit

Tags: postgresql

Имею:

```
0000 0101 - выбран 2 параметр, он активен
```

как мне запросом это привести к виду:

```
0000 1001 - выбран 3 параметр, он активен
```

такой запрос

```
select set_bit(5::bit(8), 4, 1)
```

вернет `00001101`, то есть мне бы занулить все первые 7 бит, а потом выставить нужный (но не трогать 8 ой)

Answer (score 1):

сдлайте с бинарними операторами. так

```
(0000 1001 & 1111 1011) | 0000 1000
```

это будет так

```
select (5 & 251) | 8
```

также зависит от типа переменной в вашей базы

**UPD**

Есть универсальный вариант

```
select (5 & ~(1 << 2)) | (1 << 3)
```

тут `5` - это задаваемое число (значение)

`<< 2` - номер бита из права который нужно убрать

`<< 3` - номер бита из права который нужно вставить

работает с любой длиной числа.

Comment: а если обратно? какой то не правильный способ

Comment: @des1roer почему? все же работает. 2) Обратно это что, нужно обратно повернуть эти 2 битика?

Comment: @des1roer обратное будет так `select (5 & ~(1 << 3)) | (1 << 2)`

Comment: я не знаю бит что нужно убрать

Comment: `вернет 00001101, то есть мне бы занулить все первые 7 бит, а потом выставить нужный (но не трогать 8 ой)` этим вы хотели сказать, что нужно удалить все бити кроме последней? тогда это будет так `select (число & 1)`

Answer (score 1):

если через хранимку

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_my_bit (
      intval integer,
      pos integer
    )
    RETURNS text AS
    $body$
    DECLARE
      returnval INTEGER;
      bufval text;
    BEGIN
      bufval = intval::bit(8)::text;
      bufval = right(bufval, 1);
      bufval = '0000000'||bufval;
      returnval = set_bit (bufval::bit(8),pos,1)::int;
      return (returnval);
    EXCEPTION
              WHEN others THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'SQLSTATE: %', SQLSTATE;
                RAISE;
    END;
    $body$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    SECURITY INVOKER
    COST 100;
```